# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, slf4j, noclassdeffounderror

We're trying to initialize a hibernate database in our Vaadin-project but it throws the following error.
We've been searching for several days, but no solution has worked so far and we are out of ideas. Hope anybody can help.
We are using NetBeans.

```
Schwerwiegend:   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Schwerwiegend:   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Schwerwiegend:   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:223)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:120)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:163)
```

Our automatically generated pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>DirectFeedback</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>DirectFeedback</name>

<properties>
    <vaadin.version>7.5.8</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <jetty.plugin.version>9.2.3.v20140905</jetty.plugin.version>
    <project.source.version>1.7</project.source.version>
    <project.target.version>1.7</project.target.version>
    <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--
      Needed when using the widgetset optimizer (custom ConnectorBundleLoaderFactory).

      For widgetset compilation, vaadin-client-compiler is automatically added on the
      compilation classpath by vaadin-maven-plugin so normally there is no need for an
      explicit dependency.
    -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.livesense</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.liveSense.misc.javax.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.5</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0.Beta-1</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j </groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.8</version>
     </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.13</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.8</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you mixing different versions of slf4j ? I see 1.5 and 1.7

Comment: And you have SLF4J-Log4J and SLF4J-JDK14 on your classpath. You should have just one SJLF4 binding (implementation).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Netbeans didn't allow me to delete the SLF4J-Log4J so i deleted SLF4J-JDK14 but result is the same.

Comment: Do a `mvn dependency:tree` and paste your output here.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen problem in your **.pom** file. "**maven install**" fails with your **.pom** file, but after the updates below, "**maven install**" works fine;

Just remove the dependency below, `maven install` is failed with this one;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Simply, update your **.pom** file (or copy/paste the updated **.pom** just down below) and then, run `maven clean` and `maven install` on the project directory via command line.

I've just run your pom file without the dependency **slf4j-api** with version **1.7.13** and `maven install` successfully worked [**BUILD SUCCESS**]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>DirectFeedback</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DirectFeedback</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <vaadin.version>7.5.8</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.2.3.v20140905</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.source.version>1.7</project.source.version>
        <project.target.version>1.7</project.target.version>
        <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.livesense</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.liveSense.misc.javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0.Beta-1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j </groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the same exception but the cause was totally different.

I was loading all the dependencies with the latest version i.e. [1.3.0-alpha4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.3.0-alpha4). In my case had to to use older version to [1.2.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3).

Below is the working dependence for me -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```